# Find out who started a goroutine (pprof)

Tags: go

When examining the output of `pprof` I can see the stacktrace of a goroutine. However I'd like to know who started (spawned?) this goroutine, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the endpoint `/debug/pprof/goroutine?debug=2` you get a slightly different output for the stack traces:

```
goroutine 859579 [running]:
runtime/pprof.writeGoroutineStacks(0x176a0e0, 0xc43403a340, 0x178d740, 0x30)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:585 +0x79
runtime/pprof.writeGoroutine(0x176a0e0, 0xc43403a340, 0x2, 0x0, 0xd)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:574 +0x44
runtime/pprof.(*Profile).WriteTo(0x178f9e0, 0x176a0e0, 0xc43403a340, 0x2, 0xc43403a340, 0xc4587b5834)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:298 +0x341
net/http/pprof.handler.ServeHTTP(0xc4587b5841, 0x9, 0x1771320, 0xc43403a340, 0xc49a7093b0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:209 +0x1a6
net/http/pprof.Index(0x1771320, 0xc43403a340, 0xc49a7093b0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:221 +0x205
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12664a8, 0x1771320, 0xc43403a340, 0xc49a7093b0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x179dde0, 0x1771320, 0xc43403a340, 0xc49a7093b0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2022 +0x7f
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc46d06ed80, 0x1771320, 0xc43403a340, 0xc49a7093b0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2202 +0x7d
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc45dc83180, 0x17734a0, 0xc4942f0600)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1579 +0x4b7
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2293 +0x44d
```

That include the `created by` line at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to view this in the graph generated by "web"?